# Xamarin.Forms toolbar: why do icons have visual glitches?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Why is the scaling in the Xamarin.Forms toolbar so bad, and how can it be fixed?  We have tried large icons and small icons, but they all exhibit this same behavior.

Source icons:

[image: Source icons]

How they appear in the iOS app toolbar:

[image: How icons appear in toolbar]

Comment: What platform do you get this result on? Are you following the according guidelines for using icons? I've never seen this behavior

Comment: Do you have the image in all sizes? hdpi, mdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi ans xxxhdpi?

Comment: looks like you're scaling the image down. Like mario said, make sure you have the proper resolution for whatever resolution your device is.

Answer (score 0):

In your native Android project you have a drawable folder with hdpi, xhdpi and xxhdpi.

Make sure you put the correct icon size in. I haven't had any issues with scaling if the correct size is implemented. Though a word of caution the emulators can sometimes do crazy things. Don't always trust your emulator for a correct visual appearance.

```
  ldpi | 24x24

  mdpi | 32x32

  hdpi | 48x48

 xhdpi | 64x64

xxhdpi | 96x96
```

Answer (score 0):

I thought that this glitch didn't look like a normal scaling artifact, and as it turns out, it wasn't a scaling artifact after all.

Our designer gave us scaled versions of our app icons, and we developers dutifully imported them into the application.  It was purely by accident that we discovered that the icons had some non-transparent white pixels around the edge of the icons, whereas the rest of the background was pure transparent.  I only noticed it when highlighting the icon in Windows Explorer:

[image: Stray white pixels]

When iOS went to convert the "full-color" PNG into a flat-color image for the toolbar, it was interpreting those white pixels as icon, instead of background.

Replacing those white pixels with transparent fixed all our problems here.